# how to install XCode 3.2.6 in Lion(10.7.3)

Tags: xcode, macos, osx-lion

i've been pulling my hair for two days in installing XCode 3.2.6 on my machine, Lion 10.7.3, but up to now I have no luck. i've followed the installation instruction here: [Installing Xcode 3.2.6 On Lion Redux](http://anatomicwax.tumblr.com/post/8064949186/installing-xcode-3-2-6-on-lion-redux)  and here [Installing Xcode 3.2.6 in Mac OS X Lion (10.7)](http://catacombae.blogspot.co.uk/2011/07/installing-xcode-326-in-mac-os-x-lion.html) but both are not working. Im always getting an installation unknown error, please refer to the attached image. Please help.. Thank you very much.[image]

Machine: Macbook 
OS: Mac OS X Lion 10.7.3
With XCode 4.3 installed

```
Apr  8 17:14:27 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Set authorization level to root for session
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Will use PK session
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Starting installation:
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Configuring volume "Mac OS X"
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Preparing disk for local booted install.
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Free space on "Mac OS X": 108.39 GB (108385030144 bytes).
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Create temporary directory "/var/folders/g8/87n3y6s561x_62y3d9h7y5480000gn/T//Install.326LicomV"
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: IFPKInstallElement (22 packages)
Apr  8 17:14:28 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Using authorization level of root for IFPKInstallElement
Apr  8 17:14:29 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Failed install preflight: Error Domain=PKInstallErrorDomain Code=102 "The package “iPhoneSDK4_3.pkg” is untrusted." UserInfo=0x7c375830 {PKInstallPackageIdentifier=com.apple.pkg.iPhoneSDK4_3, NSLocalizedDescription=The package “iPhoneSDK4_3.pkg” is untrusted., NSUnderlyingError=0x7c3e0d30 "The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED", NSURL=../Packages/iPhoneSDK4_3.pkg -- file://localhost/Volumes/Xcode%20and%20iOS%20SDK/Xcode%20and%20iOS%20SDK.mpkg/}
Apr  8 17:14:29 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Install failed: The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.
Apr  8 17:14:29 mo-macbook Installer[326]: IFDInstallController 7AE66E10 state = 7
Apr  8 17:14:29 mo-macbook Installer[326]: Displaying 'Install Failed' UI.
Apr  8 17:14:29 mo-macbook Installer[326]: 'Install Failed' UI displayed message:'An unknown installation error occurred.

The Installer encountered an error that caused the installation to fail. Contact the software manufacturer for assistance.'.
```

Comment: What's with the title of that window and the icon in it?  Anyway, in Installer.app's Window menu, you'll find an option to show the install log.  What does it say?  For what it's worth, although this has worked for me and others, it's remotely possible that Apple changed the Xcode 3.2.6 package on their site or 10.7's Installer to prevent this, if they think it's leading to a support nightmare.

Comment: please see the update for the installation log, hope that would help to solve the error

Answer (score 5):

I solved this error by setting my clock to 01-01-2012.

It's weird, but installation was completed successfully after that.

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I got this working. This error "**The operation couldn’t be completed. CSSMERR_TP_CERT_EXPIRED**" point me to this site [Fixing packages with expired signatures](http://managingosx.wordpress.com/2012/03/24/fixing-packages-with-expired-signatures/).

Steps:

1. Flattened the disc image using this script [flatpkgfixer.py](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/8119814/flatpkgfixer.py)
2. Mount my disc image
3. Execute this command in Terminal, **export COMMAND_LINE_INSTALL=1**
4. And **open "/Volumes/Xcode and iOS SDK/Xcode and iOS SDK.mpkg"**

And XCode 3.2.6 installs successfully on my Lion 10.7.3. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Setting the date back to 2011 worked for me. The exact error I saw in the log was IFDInstallController 7912F940 state = 7

Answer (score 0):

Run Software Update.  It should offer the "Apple Software Installer Update".  Install that.  I think it should fix the issue.

Comment: Hi Ken, I've updated my system software, but this seems not to fix the issue.

Comment: Yes, I got the same installation log.

Comment: Hmm.  Then I don't know.  I had the same error the other day and that update fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved to install it by setting the system date to year 2011.
And it worked like a charm!